# Using Custom Login Form (Vaadin Components with Spring Security/ROO

Tags: user-interface, spring-security, vaadin, custom-formatting

I have completed setting up Spring Security using the roo shell as a guide and it has generated several views, amongst them is the login.jspx. I am trying to create a custom login form using Vaadin's Visual editor and Eclipse, how can i redirect the user to my login form and then use Spring Security to validate and authenticate the user as well as start a session management? I am really trying to avoid JSP since the rest of my application is using Vaadin as its Core Front-End

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vaadin has some limitations on the login form.
Have a look at: https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.loginform.html so you will notice what I mean.

You can also have a look at the vaadin wiki (https://vaadin.com/wiki). There are several articles on your topic. You may find your solution there :)

kind regards

.zip

Comment: almost a year since i asked this question. But i found a better solution that allows me to build my own front end login form with vaadin using Apache shiro as my security. Works much better